# Select random 3000 lines from a file with awk codes

Tags: random, awk, lines

I want to select randomly  3000 lines from a sample.file which contains 8000 lines.
I will do that with awk codes or do from command line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 13):

If you have gnu sort, it's easy:

```
sort -R FILE | head -n3000
```

If you have gnu shuf, it's even easier:

```
shuf -n3000 FILE
```

Comment: Thanks!  Nice to know that shuf is written specifically for this task.

Comment: Great answer. If you need to choose a large number of random choices from a shorter list/sample you may need the `-r` option to enable replacement. For example `shuf -n5000 -r list-of-15-choices.txt`

Answer (score 5):

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand();}
{a[NR]=$0}
END{for(i=1; i<=3000; i++){x=int(rand()*NR) + 1; print a[x];}}' yourFile
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed as per Glenn's comment:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  a=8000; l=3000
  srand(); nr[x]
  while (length(nr) <= l) 
    nr[int(rand() * a) +  1]    
  }
NR in nr
  ' infile
```

P.S. Passing an array to the length built-in function is not portable, you've been warned :)

Comment: +1, nice answer. In your BEGIN block, after you populate the `nr` array, you might want to check it's size to ensure you have 3000 distinct numbers.

Comment: This answer differs from the `sort` / `shuf` answer in as much as the records will always appear in the same order that they appear in the original file. This may or may not be of concern to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `awk`, `sort`, `head/tail` and `sed` to do this, such as with:

```
pax$ seq 1 100 | awk '
...$    BEGIN {srand()}
...$          {print rand() " " $0}
...$ ' | sort | head -5 | sed 's/[^ ]* //'
57
25
80
51
72
```

which, as you can see, selects five random lines from the one hundred generated in `seq 1 100`.

The `awk` trick prefixes each and every line in the file with a random number and space of the format `"0.237788 "`, then sort (obviously) sorts it based on that random number.

Then you use `head` (or `tail` if you don't have a `head`) to get the first (or last) `N` lines.

Finally, the `sed` will strip off the random number and space and the start of each line.

For your specific case, you could use something like (on one line):

```
awk 'BEGIN {srand()} {print rand() " " $0}' file8000.txt
    | sort
    | tail -3000
    | sed 's/[^ ]* //'
    >file3000.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I used these commands, and got what I wanted:

```
awk 'BEGIN {srand()} {print rand() " " $0}' examples/data_text.txt | sort -n | tail -n 80 | awk '{printf "%1d %s %s\n",$2, $3, $4}' > examples/crossval.txt
```

which in fact randomly selects 80 lines from the input file.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell:

```
Get-Content myfile | Get-Random -Count 3000
```

or shorter:

```
gc myfile | random -c 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you only need approximately 3000 lines, this is an easy method:

```
awk -v N=`cat FILE | wc -l` 'rand()<3000/N' FILE
```

The part between the backticks (`) gives the number of lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

For a huge file that I didn't want to shuffle, this worked out well and pretty fast:

sed -u -n 'l1p;l2p; ... ;l1000p;l1000q'

The -u option reduces buffering, and l1, l2, ... l1000 are random and sorted line numbers obtained from R (would be just as good with python or perl).