# random split files with specific proportion

Tags: random, awk, split

I want to randomly 80/20 split a file using awk.

I have read and tried the option found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514896/select-random-3000-lines-from-a-file-with-awk-codes) in which something like the following proposed:

```
$ awk -v N=`cat FILE | wc -l` 'rand()<3000/N' FILE
```

works great if you want a random selection.

However, is it possible to alter this awk in order to split the one file into two files of 80/20 (or any other) proportion?

Comment: What do you mean with randomly 80/20 split?

Comment: For example split the file into two: 1 part 80% and the 2 part 20%. If I have 1000 lines --- 800 in one file and 200 in the other -- but a random selection of 800 in one and a random selection of 200 in the other.

Comment: Do you need exactly 80/20, or approximately 80/20 - If approximately is good enough then something like `if random(100) < 80 then write_to_file1 else write_to_file2` would be a workable pattern. If you need an exact split you might completely shuffle the lines in the file, then split...

Comment: Approximately is good enough. However, in what language are you suggesting is the optimal way to do this then?

Comment: @owwoow14 Well, there's likely not one language that produces the one true "optimal way". If you want to use the random number generator approach, obviously there's a requirement that a random number generator and an `if...then...else` construct be available in the language... `awk`, `bash`, `zsh`, `perl`, `python`, `ruby`, `lua`, `C`, `C++`, `Fortran`, `Ada`, `Cobol` and many many more would all meet that minimum threshold. My original comment was really just to show the pattern as language-agnostic pseudo-code - it should be fairly simple to translate it into your language of choice...

Comment: Are you totally committed to using awk for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With gawk, you'd write

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {srand()}
    {f = FILENAME (rand() <= 0.8 ? ".80" : ".20"); print > f}
' file
```

Example:

```
seq 100 > 100.txt
gawk 'BEGIN {srand()} {f = FILENAME (rand() <= 0.8 ? ".80" : ".20"); print > f}' 100.txt
wc -l 100.txt*
```

```
100 100.txt
 23 100.txt.20
 77 100.txt.80
200 total
```

---

To ensure 20 lines in the "20" file:

```sh
$ paste -d $'\034' <(seq $(wc -l < "$file") | sort -R) "$file" \
| awk -F $'\034' -v file="$file" '{
    f = file ($1 <= 20 ? ".20" : ".80")
    print $2 > f
}'

$ wc -l "$file"*
100 testfile
 20 testfile.20
 80 testfile.80
200 total
```

`\034` is the ASCII `FS` character, unlikely to appear in a text file.

`sort -R` to shuffle the input may not be portable. It's in GNU and BSD sort though.

Comment: How to adapt this to guarantee that '100.txt.20" has 20 lines and "100.txt.80" has 80 lines?