# How to randomly extract FASTA sequences using Python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, extract, fasta

I have the following sequences which is in a fasta format with sequence header and its nucleotides. How can I randomly extract the sequences. For example I would like to randomly select 2 sequences out of the total sequences. There are tools provided to do so is to extract according to percentage but not the number of sequences. Can anyone help me?

**A.fasta**

```
>chr1:1310706-1310726
GACGGTTTCCGGTTAGTGGAA
>chr1:901959-901979
GAGGGCTTTCTGGAGAAGGAG
>chr1:983001-983021
GTCCGCTTGCGGGACCTGGGG
>chr1:984333-984353
CTGGAATTCCGGGCGCTGGAG
>chr1:1154147-1154167
GAGATCGTCCGGGACCTGGGT
```

**Expected Output**

```
>chr1:1154147-1154167
GAGATCGTCCGGGACCTGGGT
>chr1:901959-901979
GAGGGCTTTCTGGAGAAGGAG
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are working with fasta files use [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO), to get `n` sequences use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from random import sample
with open("foo.fasta") as f:
    seqs = SeqIO.parse(f,"fasta")
    print(sample(list(seqs), 2))
```

Output:

```
[SeqRecord(seq=Seq('GAGATCGTCCGGGACCTGGGT', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='chr1:1154147-1154167', name='chr1:1154147-1154167', description='chr1:1154147-1154167', dbxrefs=[]), SeqRecord(seq=Seq('GTCCGCTTGCGGGACCTGGGG', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='chr1:983001-983021', name='chr1:983001-983021', description='chr1:983001-983021', dbxrefs=[])]
```

You can extract the strings if necessary:

```
 print([(seq.name,str(seq.seq)) for seq in  sample(list(seqs),2)])
 [('chr1:1310706-1310726', 'GACGGTTTCCGGTTAGTGGAA'), ('chr1:983001-983021', 'GTCCGCTTGCGGGACCTGGGG')]
```

If the lines were always in pairs and you skipped the metadata at the top you could  zip:

```
from random import sample

with open("foo.fasta") as f:
    print(sample(list(zip(f, f)), 2))
```

Which will give you pairs of lines in tuples:

```
[('>chr1:983001-983021\n', 'GTCCGCTTGCGGGACCTGGGG\n'), ('>chr1:984333-984353\n', 'CTGGAATTCCGGGCGCTGGAG\n')]
```

To get the lines ready to be written:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from random import sample
with open("foo.fasta") as f:
    seqs = SeqIO.parse(f, "fasta")
    samps = ((seq.name, seq.seq) for seq in  sample(list(seqs),2))
    for samp in samps:
        print(">{}\n{}".format(*samp))
```

Output:

```
>chr1:1310706-1310726
GACGGTTTCCGGTTAGTGGAA
>chr1:983001-983021
GTCCGCTTGCGGGACCTGGGG
```

Comment: May I know how to get rid of the [('....'),('....')] and make the output presentable?

Comment: Just like the expected output because i will write the output in a file later.

Comment: I edited the answer, you can use str.format and unpack the tuples

Comment: Is it possible to use any seed so that I can reproduce the same set of samples in future?

Answer (score 2):

Given the file format that you have shown, and assuming that the file is not too large, you don't need any external module (e.g. biopython) to do this:

```
import random

with open('A.fasta') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
    for i in random.sample(range(0, len(data), 2), 2):
        print data[i]
        print data[i+1]
```

**Example output:**

```
>chr1:984333-984353
CTGGAATTCCGGGCGCTGGAG
>chr1:901959-901979
GAGGGCTTTCTGGAGAAGGAG
```

This simply selects 2 random sequence headers (those lines from A.fasta with even indices in `data`) and the line following it.

If your file is large then external modules might have optimisations to cope with larger data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about Fasta, but Python has a Fasta module (you need to install it first).

```
>>> from pyfasta import Fasta

>>> f = Fasta('tests/test1.fasta')
>>> sorted(f.keys())
['chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3']
```

Then you can use the sample function from Python's Random module and pick as many as you want at random...

```
from random import sample
sample(f, how_many_you_want)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys,random
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_protein

# Use: python   scriptname.py   number_of_random_seq   infile.fasta   outfile.fasta

infile = sys.argv[2]                                #Name of the input file
seq = list(SeqIO.parse(infile,"fasta"))             #Create a list with all the sequence records
print "Input fasta file = ", infile

totseq = len(seq)                                   #Total number of sequences in the input file
print "Number of sequences in the original file = ", totseq

randseq = int(sys.argv[1])                          #Number of random sequences desired
print "Number of random sequences desired = ", randseq

if randseq > totseq:
  print "The requested number of random sequences is greater that the total number of input sequences. Exiting."
  exit()

outfile = sys.argv[3]                               #Name of the output file
print "Output fasta file = ", outfile

outrandseq = []
outlist = []
print "Randomly chosen output sequences:"

for i in range(randseq):
  choose = random.randint(1,totseq-1)               #Choose a random sequence record number
  for j in range(len(outrandseq)):                  #Test to see if the random sequence record number has already been chosen
    if choose == outrandseq[j]:
      choose = random.randint(1,totseq-1)           #Choose a new random sequence record number if the current one has already been chosen
  outrandseq.append(choose)
  print choose
  outseq = seq[choose]
  outlist.append(outseq)                            #Append seq record to output list

SeqIO.write(outlist, outfile, "fasta")              #Write the output list to the outfile

exit()
```

Comment: I've used this extensively in my own work. It's fine. I'm a part-time hack so it may not be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys,random
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_protein

# I use this from small numbers of sequences (input file up to 10000 sequences) and it works fine. 
# For very large sequence sets it may be too slow -- I just have not tried.

# Use: python   scriptname.py   number_of_random_seq   infile.fasta   outfile.fasta

infile = sys.argv[2]                                #Name of the input file
seq = list(SeqIO.parse(infile,"fasta"))             #Create a list with all the sequence records
print "Input fasta file = ", infile

totseq = len(seq)                                   #Total number of sequences in the input file
print "Number of sequences in the original file = ", totseq

numrandseq = int(sys.argv[1])                       #Number of random sequences desired
print "Number of random sequences desired = ", numrandseq

if numrandseq > totseq:
  print "The requested number of random sequences is greater that the total number of input sequences. Exiting."
  exit()

outfile = sys.argv[3]                               #Name of the output file
print "Output fasta file = ", outfile

outrandseqset = []
i = 1
for i in range(numrandseq):                         #Create a list of random sequence record numbers for output
  choice = random.randint(1,totseq)
  outrandseqset.append(choice)

i = 1
j = 1
duplicate = 1
while duplicate:                                    #Make sure no sequences are duplicated in the list
    duplicate = 0
    for i in range(numrandseq):
      for j in range(i+1, numrandseq):
        if outrandseqset[i] == outrandseqset[j]:
            outrandseqset[j] = random.randint(1,totseq)
            duplicate = 1


i = 1
print "Randomly chosen output sequences:"
for i in range(numrandseq):
  print outrandseqset[i]

outlist = []
i = 1
for i in range(numrandseq):                         #Create the list of seq records to be written to the output file
  seqnum = outrandseqset[i]
  outseq = seq[seqnum]
  outlist.append(outseq)

SeqIO.write(outlist, outfile, "fasta")              #Write the output list to the outfile

exit()
```

Comment: New version version of my script that checks for duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Depends if you have unix `sort` or `shuf` installed.  If so, its very easy [Select random 3000 lines from a file with awk codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514896/select-random-3000-lines-from-a-file-with-awk-codes)

1. Create a list of headers

> grep '>' A.fasta >FILE

2. Then select 2 random lines from that file

> CONTIGS=`sort -R FILE | head -n2|tr "\n" " "`

or

> CONTIGS=`shuf -n2 FILE|tr "\n" " "`

Then, use samtools to extract

> `samtools faidx A.fasta $CONTIGS`