# Extracting sequences in Python

Tags: python, string, split, sequence, bioinformatics

I have a file that looks like this:

```
>sequence_name_16hj51
CAACCTTGGCCAT
>sequence_name_158ghni52
AATTGGCCTTGGA
>sequence_name_468rth
AAGGTTCCA
```

I would like to obtain this:
`['CAACCTTGGCCAT', 'AATTGGCCTTGGA', 'AAGGTTCCA']`

I have a list with all the sequence names titled `title_finder`. When I try to use:

```
for i in range(0,len(title_finder)):
    seq = seq.split(title_finder[i])
    print seq
```

I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Desktop/Python/consensus new.py", line 23, in <module>
    seq = seq.split(title_finder[i])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Can somebody help me out?

EDIT: Sometimes some sequences span multiple lines and so I get more than one string when I do it with a for loop.

Comment: You can only split a string, and you get a list. Your loop splits repeatedly, so you fail after the first go-round.

Comment: use BioPython http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265282/how-to-randomly-extract-fasta-sequences-using-python/31265485#31265485

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing bioinformatics, you should really consider installing [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page).

```
from Bio import SeqIO
with open('your_file.fasta') as f:
    return [str(record.seq) for record in SeqIO.parse(f, "fasta")]
```

If you want to do it in pure Python, then this wil work:

```
with open('your_file.fasta') as f:
    print [line.rstrip() for line in f if not line.startswith('>')]
```

Comment: I second the use of Biopython, it handles FASTA files for you and does a lot of the dirty work. You can always convert it to a string if you really need a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to split a list which gave you that `AttributeError`, instead of that you can read your file line and check if the line doesn't starts with `>` then preserve it.

```
With open('file_nam') as f:
    my_patterns=[line.rstrip() for line in f in not line.startswith('>')]
```

Also as an alternative and pythonic way if you are sure that the patterns are in odd lines you can use `itertools.islice` to slice your file object :

```
from itertools import islice
With open('file_nam') as f:
     my_my_patterns=list(islice(f,1,None,2))
```

And note that if you just want to loop over your patterns you don't need to convert the result of `islice` to list you can simply iterate over your iterator.

Comment: You'll need to add `rstrip()` after `line`, because now the sequences contain the newline at the end.

Comment: `islice` includes the `\n` as well

Answer (score 0):

assume your file is seq.in, then you can do this to get your list:

```
In [17]: with open ('seq.in','r') as f:
          extracted_list=[line[:-1] for line in f if line[0]!='>']

In [18]: extracted_list
Out[18]: ['CAACCTTGGCCAT', 'AATTGGCCTTGGA', 'AAGGTTCCA']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line = ""

import re

with open('test') as f:
  lines = [line.rstrip()  for line in f if not re.search('sequence_name', line)]
```

print(lines)

['CAACCTTGGCCAT', 'AATTGGCCTTGGA', 'AAGGTTCCA']