# Sample 10000 random rows from a 200GB dataset

Tags: bash, dataset, bigdata

I am trying to sample 10000 random rows from a large dataset with ~3 billion rows (with headers). I've considered using `shuf -n 1000 input.file > output.file` but this seems quite slow (>2 hour run time with my current available resources).

I've also used `awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {a[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1; i<=10; i++){x=int(rand()*NR) + 1; print a[x];}}' input.file > output.file` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7515513/13590525) for a percentage of lines from smaller files, though I am new to awk and don't know how to include headers.

I wanted to know if there was a more efficient solution to sampling a subset (e.g. 10000 rows) of data from the 200GB dataset.

Comment: `shuf` is going to be the fastest.

Comment: there are multiple ways to do this in R on a dataframe, but I dont know if this is going to be faster

Comment: If you're OK with stratified sampling, you can split the large data file into say 1000 partitions of 3m records each, and take 10 sample from each and merge the samples back.

Answer (score 0):

Something in awk. Supply it with random seed (`$RANDOM` in Bash) and number `n` of wanted records. It counts the lines with `wc -l` and uses that count to select randomly `n` values between *1—lines[1]* in `file` and outputs them. Can't really say anything about speed, I don't even have 200 GBs of disk. (:

```
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM -v n=10000 '
BEGIN {
    cmd="wc -l " ARGV[1]                          # use wc  for line counting
    if(ARGV[1]==""||n==""||(cmd | getline t)<=0)  # require all parameters
        exit 1                                    # else exit
    split(t,lines)                                # wc -l returns "lines filename"
    srand(seed)                                   # use the seed
    while(c<n) {                                  # keep looping n times
        v=int((lines[1]) * rand())+1              # get a random line number
        if(!(v in a)){                            # if its not used yet
            a[v]                                  # use it
            ++c                                   
        }
    }
}
(NR in a)' file                                   # print if NR in selected
```

Testing with dataset from `seq 1 100000000`. `shuf -n 10000 file` took about 6 seconds where the awk above took about 18 s.

Comment: This worked pretty well with small files, and it's worth a shot to run this with the large file to at least compare with the runtime of shuf. I'll try to report back in a couple of days.

Comment: Tested with awk for the heck of it and it took ~2 hours with awk as opposed to ~1.7 hours with shuf.

Comment: @Geode Surprisingly not so bad. Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any program written in a scripting language can beat the `shuf` in the context of this question. Anyway, this is my try in `bash`. Run it with `./scriptname input.file > output.file`

```
#!/bin/bash

samplecount=10000
datafile=$1
[[ -f $datafile && -r $datafile ]] || {
    echo "Data file does not exists or is not readable" >&2
    exit 1
}

linecount=$(wc -l "$datafile")
linecount=${linecount%% *}
pickedlinnum=(-1)
mapfile -t -O1 pickedlinnum < <(
    for ((i = 0; i < samplecount;)); do
        rand60=$((RANDOM + 32768*(RANDOM + 32768*(RANDOM + 32768*RANDOM))))
        linenum=$((rand60 % linecount))
        if [[ -z ${slot[linenum]} ]]; then # no collision
            slot[linenum]=1
            echo ${linenum}
            ((++i))
        fi
    done | sort -n)

for ((i = 1; i <= samplecount; ++i)); do
    mapfile -n1 -s$((pickedlinnum[i] - pickedlinnum[i-1] - 1))
    echo -n "${MAPFILE[0]}"
done < "$datafile"
```